# Using pg_dump to export multiple schemas from like a par file

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

In order to export using pg_dump, I'm aware i need to do something like this to export multiple schemas

As an example:
`pg_dump -n user1 -n user2 -f backup.sql`

but what if i have like 10 schemas, instead of using "-n" n number of times is there a better way to define the schema list, like in a text file and somehow render in a pg_dump commandline?

thanks

Comment: 1) From [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) `-n pattern` where: "The pattern parameter is interpreted as a pattern according to the same rules used by psql's \d commands (see Patterns below), so multiple schemas can also be selected by writing wildcard characters in the pattern." So do the schema names have a consistent pattern you can match? 2) From same link: `-N pattern` "Do not dump any schemas matching pattern." So would it be simpler to filter out schemas you don't want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using patterns o regular expressions as appears in official docs

`-n pattern --schema=pattern`
Dump only schemas matching pattern; this selects both the schema itself, and all its contained objects.
Multiple schemas can be selected by writing multiple `-n` switches. The pattern parameter is interpreted
as a pattern according to the same rules used by psql's `\d` commands (see Patterns below), so multiple
schemas can also be selected by writing wildcard characters in the pattern. When using wildcards, be
careful to quote the pattern if needed to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcards; see Examples
below.

To dump all schemas whose names start with east or west and end in gsm, excluding any schemas whose names
contain the word test:

```
   $ pg_dump -n 'east*gsm' -n 'west*gsm' -N '*test*' mydb > db.sql
```

The same, using regular expression notation to consolidate the switches:

```
   $ pg_dump -n '(east|west)*gsm' -N '*test*' mydb > db.sql
```

Or with a shell script and a text file containing names of schemas, one by line

```
#!/bin/bash
cat schemas.txt | while read schema || [[ -n $schema ]];
do
  cmd="pg_dump -n '${schema}' postgres > ${schema}.sql"
  printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
  eval "$cmd"
done
```

where postgres is your database.
And additionally a version for all the selected schemas in one dump file

```
#!/bin/bash
cat schemas.txt | (while read schema || [[ -n $schema ]];
do
 params+="-n '${schema}' "
done
cmd="pg_dump $params postgres > some_schemas.sql"
printf '%s\n' "$cmd" 
eval "$cmd")
```

Comment: The schemas are in fact users having objects , so names cannot have a pattern unfortunately. 
I was wondering like in oracle call a par file having a list of users

Comment: No you can't do that.

Comment: hey it does not work for some reason ? it does  take into account two schemas in cat file ```dump=/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/daily-backup-"$d.sql"
log=/var/lib/pgsql/scripts/errors-backup-"$d".txt
dbname=prd

cat schemas.txt | while read schema || [[ -n $schema ]];
do
 cmd="pg_dump -w -U postgres -b '${schema}' -v -f $dump $dbname 2>$log"
 printf '%s\n' "$cmd"
 eval "$cmd"
done```

Comment: i mean to say i dont want an individual backup but one backups for all schemas. The above does each user separately

Comment: As you mentioned, it's necessary a version that creates one dump for all selected schemas. So i added it.